# Configurable Products and Group Pricing

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1, group-price, pricing

Does Magento allow customer group pricing for configurable products that are not the same per configuration. Let me explain.

If you have a Retail price for a configurable product of $40.00. There are two configurable products. Large and Small. There is also a group price of each, however the pricing of these two products for the group ID is not logically discounted.

Retail - $40.00 Small
Retail - $50.00 Large
Group Price - $15.00 Small
Group Price - $36.00 Large

You can see the discount group pricing is not across the board equal. The group price is not simple -$10.00 for each product, Large and Small. Ideas?  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have customer group prices, special prices or tier prices per associated product with configurable products.

Magento completely ignores prices of associated products in the configurable product type. You can specify a price difference for each associated product within a configurable product, but the base price with its modifications is always taken from the configurable product itself.

Conclusion is: You cannot achieve what you try to do without custom extensions. There are some extensions around that change how pricing for configurable products work, but due to these substantial changes there are always rewrites of important core classes and you should think twice if you really need it.

This extension is a good example: [Better Configurable Products](http://de.nr-apps.com/store/bcp-better-configurable-products.html)

But you should not expect it to work out of the box, at least not if you use a custom theme. This is not a "one click install and forget" extension, it should be installed and configured by a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Associated Products tab of the configurable product, and add price adjustment per simple product.

Example: http://cdn.aschroder.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/associated-products.png

Comment: You could also take a look at the `Simple Configurable Products` in Magento Connect, it's free. This one takes the prices from the simple instead of price correction on a base price(which is also fine if you do not have a lot of products to maintain)